# Laravel accessor returning different month from the one in the database

Tags: php, laravel

I've got the following code. The first function works as expected when I output

`{{ $event->date_and_time }}` in my blade.

But, when try `{{ $event->month }}` I don't get the correct month. No matter the month in the database, the output is always JULY. e.g this `2225-12-12T05:46` from the `db` outputs July instead of Dec. Can't figure out what it is that I'm missing.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'description',
    'date_and_time',
    'location',
    'price',
    'activity_status',
    'contact',
    'slug',
    'user_id',
];

public function getDateAndTimeAttribute($date_and_time)
{
    $date_and_time = date_create($date_and_time);
    return date_format($date_and_time, "F d, h:ia");
}

public function getMonthAttribute($date_and_time)
{
    $date_and_time = date_create($date_and_time);
    return date_format($date_and_time, "M");
}
```

Comment: what value would be passed as `$date_and_time` to this accessor, `getMonthAttribute`? unless there is an attribute named `month` there is nothing to pass to the accessor ... `date_create` is creating a date for the current date (which is in July) since there is no value given to it, hence the month is always July atm

Comment: Time zones are a thing, try verifying that the timezone is correct, try using Carbon which is built into laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your accessor has no value being passed to it since it is an accessor that isn't for an attribute, it is virtual. So `date_create` isn't getting a value to work with so it is returning the current date and time which is a date in July; hence it always says July as the month. You would need to get the attribute `date_and_time` and use that to pass to `date_create` and then get the Month from that.

```
public function getMonthAttribute()
{
    // to get the DateTime from the original string
    $date_and_time = date_create($this->getRawOriginal('date_and_time'));
    // or to get the DateTime object from the formatted date from the `date_and_time` accessor
    $date_and_time = date_create($this->date_and_time);

    return date_format($date_and_time, "M");
}
```

On another note, use Carbon when you can as you can cast date and time fields to Carbon objects via Eloquent.

Comment: Works and the explanation makes sense as well, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing parameter `$date_and_time` to accessor function, use `$this->date_and_time`. So in your code you have to edit to this:

```
public function getDateAndTimeAttribute()
{
    $date_and_time = date_create($this->date_and_time);
    return date_format($date_and_time, "F d, h:ia");
}


public function getMonthAttribute()
    {
        $date_and_time = date_create($this->date_and_time);
        return date_format($date_and_time, "M");
    }
```

Or even better you may use `Carbon` built-in library. So you can do only this:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'date_and_time',
        'location',
        'price',
        'activity_status',
        'contact',
        'slug',
        'user_id',
    ];

protected $dates = ['date_and_time'];
```

And you can just access to it like `$event->date_and_time->format('F d, h:ia')` and if you want to get month then just `$event->date_and_time->format('M')`